# C# SMTP mail sending usually fails due to lack of credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

It seems that when you use SmtpClient class and MailMessage to send emails, everything works fine. And it does send it. However, some servers, such as your business Exchange Server or Gmail.com or whatever services, sometimes reject these emails (because they could be phishing sites or spam sites?)

I'm using this and a lot of places reject the email I believe:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
 Host = smtpClient,
 Timeout = 40000, // 40 seconds
 DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
};
```

How do you work around this? Do you have to use login credentials to some recognized / white-listed server so that it is authorized and trusted email?

I could use something like GMAIL authentication, but my server should be allowed to send emails, it shouldn't have to rely on gmail.

Comment: What host are you using? (e.g. what is the value of the `smtpClient` variable?)

Comment: localhost, it's a local server with a very normal smtp server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long ago there were many servers on the Internet that provided the service delivery of e-mail without asking too many questions about who was using the service.
Then came the **SPAMMERS!**.
A server that was sending mail freely around the world was no longer a benefactor of the internet, but a problem.
Nowadays it is increasingly difficult to find a server that sends mail on the Internet without asking for credentials.

Your e-mail server (smtp.yourbusiness.com or whatever you want) does not trust you.
When you ask it to send an email for you, it wants to know who you are.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient  
smtp.Host = "smtp.yourbusiness.com"; 
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("your_user_name_on_smtpserver", "your_password_on_smtpserver"); 
smtp.Credentials = credentials;
```

Comment: Are you saying that my own localhost smtp server is rejecting ASP.NET C# code emails? Because I believe it is for example, my business email that is rejecting the localhost smtp on the server's email. Because the business SMTP does not recognize the localhost smtp server.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is not that the messages are not sent but that they are not received.

Comment: In that case, if the MX Target or the MDA on the MX target refuses to accept or to delivery the mail in the inbox, usually they send back a message with the reason.

Comment: On my local dev environment. I send email (but there is no SMTP server locally), so it gives me an error. On my web-based dev environment, I send email and everything works without errors and it says it sent the email. However, when I check my email using Gmail or when I use my business email with Microsoft Exchange Server, it doesn't ever receive an email. This same code works fine in a completely different environment with different mail services though.

Answer (score 2):

are you setting the sender mail address and can your mail server be resolved by reverse dns lookup? Some spam filters distrust mail servers they can't reverse lookup. If you for instance make your mail server send mails using a bogus or foreign mail domain, spam filters will probably pick this up and filter your mail. If you have set up a SPF record for your domain and your sending mail server isn't in that record, mails from that server will also often be filtered by spam filters. Another reason could be an IP address from a range known to be dynamically assigned by internet providers. Mail servers sending from these address ranges are mostly spam bots and are therefore often also filtered.

Answer (score 0):

To send GMail you need to specify a number of settings - yes you'll need to use authentication (GMail wouldn't open up their relay to everyone, or they'd get used for spamming).

If I recall correctly you need to send on TCP port 587, enable SSL, host to `mail.google.com` and provide a username and password on your `SmtpClient` to get Gmail to actually send it - neglecting one of those usually generates an email back from them telling you what you've forgotten.

**Edit**: Just to clarify on the username and password bit; you'd need to create a new [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) with the username and password for your GMail account, and set the `Credentials` property of your `SmtpClient` to that.

Answer (score 0):

If i interpret your question correctly: the messages are sent our from your server, but they are trapped in the spamfilters at the receiving end?

If this is the problem, it has nothing to to with the way you are sending the messages but much more with the content of your message and the characteristics of your server. So it does not matter what credentials you use or if you send it with SmtpClient or any other class. Moving to Gmail does not help and Gmail has a limit to the number of messages you can send.

Spam filters like spam assassin use rules. Match too many: your message is considered spam.

Have a look here for an example:

http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_3_x.html

So make sure your message does not get too high a score and it will go trough.

Comment: Good information! I believe my message is very simplistic. Giving out username/passwords for the account they made. So I think it is credential-related. My SMTP server is either not sending the emails, or it is sending them and because the SMTP server I have is not a well known server, the receiving SMTP servers are rejecting them.

Comment: You should first determine with certainty if your server is sending them out or not before you continue